# Making your program compatible with different decimal separators

Tags: c#, decimalformat, tryparse

So far I've been coding using a comma `,` as my decimal separator, and after 55k+ lines of code I was happy with it, but then.. I was requested to make my code compatible with a dot`.` decimal separator.

It's the first time I've coded, and oh boy, I'm finding trouble every step of the way.

I know I can get the decimal separator using

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`

But is there a way that can right from the `Initialization()` make all of my `tryParses` `Convert.ToDouble` `Convert.ToDecimal` compatible with whatever separator I give him?

I don't wanna change the culture info, (unless it helps), I'd rather make the program identify whatever separator I give him whenver he handles numbers.

Comment: well there is `TryParseExact` but why don't you try to change `CurrentCulture` (*it might really help*) and the code you already have? (Maybe you don't wanna change your 55k+ lines of code ;) ) (**BTW** you don't have to change your system settings - you can set the current culture even based on your current thread)

Comment: I'm trying to set `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` But it says `CurrentCulture` Is a read only property or indexer. And yes, I'd rather not change the code because it took me 1 year to write this down. But i'm ready to do it if it's needed. I've never looked this theme, and now I've got so many tabs about this open that I can only see their icon. Is there a jump-start guide/info about it? Thanks for answering by the way! :)

Comment: you need to set [`Thread.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)